# Why $y$ is a rational integer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I was reading that solution of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{−n}]$ is not a UFD here [Conclude that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{−n}]$ is not a UFD.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310721/conclude-that-mathbbz-sqrt%e2%88%92n-is-not-a-ufd/311202#311202)

But I do not understand this line "So either $d = 1, 2$ or $\gcd(y,\sqrt{-n}) \not = 1$ in which case $n|y$ because $y$ is a rational integer." Specifically, I do not understand the following:

1- why $d = 1, 2$ or $\gcd(y,\sqrt{-n}) \not = 1$?

2-and why in this case $n|y$?

3-and why  $y$ is a rational integer?

Could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: 1. Because if $\gcd(y,\sqrt{-n}) = 1$ then $d \mid 2$. 2. Because $\gcd(a,b) \mid \gcd(a,b^2)$. 3. Because it was assumed to be an integer